# How to identify buttons created using a loop. Please assist

Tags: html, jsp, loops

Following is the code, where the button Generate Key is getting created dynamically. For each record I get from the table, I create a button against it on the page. I want to capture which button was clicked and then use the values in that row to manipulate something.

```
<table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th>File ID</th>
<th>Generate Key</th>
</tr>
<%
 Connection con = DbConnector.getConnection();
 PreparedStatement pstm = null;
 String sql = "select u.uniquserid, t.filename, t.status, t.cloud, t.date_, t.report,     t.FileID from transaction t join user u on u.userid = t.user order by t.date_ desc;";
 pstm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
 ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();
 while (rs.next()) { %>

 <tr>
   <td><%=rs.getString(7)%></td>
        <% if (rs.getString(3).contains("s")) {%>
        <%request.getSession().setAttribute("PassFID", rs.getString(7));%>
   <td><input type="button" value='Generate Key' onclick=""></input></td>
   <%} else {%>
   <td></td>                                            
   <%}%>
 </tr>
 <%}%>
</table>
```

Comment: use `uniquserid` as id of button OR better use anchor tag by setting href value using `uniquserid` then implement a `doGet()` in servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery to do your task.

Change your html code to these lines of code.

```
<form method="post" action="#" name="Form" id="Form" >
<input type="button" value="one" id="One"/> 
<input type="button" value="two" id="Two"/>
</form>
```

And add these lines in your script

```
$('input:button').click(function() {
alert($(this).val());
var value=$(this).val();
var url='hello?good=';
url+=value;
$("#Form").attr("action",url); 
$("#Form").submit();   
});
```

You can use jquery 1.7.1 and above. Hope this helps you. Happy Coding :)